# Can you work your way out of a selected div to get information?

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT**

The button is nested in such a fashion:

The button is triggered by

```js
$(document).on("click" , ".down-arrow" , function() {

});
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="this is the div I am after">
        <!-- To get this text -->
    </div>

    <div class="down-arrow" id="10">
        <!-- this is the div that has the arrow button -->
        <img src="downarrow.png" id="10down" width="100%" height="auto">
        <img src="uparrow.png" style="display:none" class="upArrow" id="10up" width="100%" height="auto">
    </div>
</div>
```

So I echoed rows and each row has a unique identifier.

The button selected lies within a div, so when I click on the button, I cannot get a piece of text within the div that contains the button.

So I used `.outerHTML` which shows the id that I am after, how can I specifically select the id which lies outside of the button using the `.outerHTML` information?

```
var selectedDiv = document.getElementById(selectedId).outerHTML;
```

Comment: which row and which id you are after.. lookslike http://xyproblem.info to me

Comment: You've tagged jQuery, but you're using JavaScript.  Are you also using jQuery?

Comment: If you want to get the element wrapping your button, you could use `document.getElementById(yourId).parentNode`. It will return the button's parent.

Comment: @vinayakj, the rows have unique identifiers as I have mentioned. I thought I was using jQuery or is jQuery only used when using the $ sign? This particular row selected (html shown above) has the id 10.

Comment: @mindastic, I will have to try that out. Actually I'm after a higher parent than this parent (down-arrow class) this is probably a bad method... but you see the arrow buttons are within the div, it's like a triple nest situation and I'm after the primary parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery (which I'll assume because you thought you were), try the following:

```js
$('.down-arrow').click({
    $(this).parent().children('.targetClass').text();
    // where targetClass is the class of whatever it is you want the text of
});
```

And if you want to go further up the DOM, add more `.parent()`s.